# How to add if else condition for sitecore experience editor in aspx Layout file

Tags: experience-editor

I need to add experience editor condition in the Sitecore aspx layout file. I tried adding this

```
<%if(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor){%>
  <span>
   <sc:Placeholder Key="standard-footer" runat="server" />
  </span>
<%}else {%>
  <a href="www.abc.com">
    <sc:Placeholder Key="standard-footer" runat="server" />
  </a>
<% } %>
```

but with that I am getting **The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)** error.

Any way of adding experience editor condition in aspx layout file.

Comment: can you try to add the `runat="server"` attribute to the `<span>` and `<a>` tag?

Comment: And put the condition just around the link (as that is the only difference)

Comment: still getting the same issue The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore StackExchange. Could you add what other controls you have defined on the page? The code block by itself is running without errors, but the error can be caused if you have dynamic controls added on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it is better to use MVC implementation to make your approach work.

But, usually, in WebForms it is can be implemented this way:

```
<a runat="server" Visible="<%#!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor%>">
  <sc:Placeholder Key="standard-footer" runat="server" />
</a>

<span runat="server" Visible="<%#Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor%>">
  <sc:Placeholder Key="standard-footer" runat="server" />
</span>
```